# Delete button on a checklist

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a delete button next to all of my text in the part "todo list, so they have to be centered with it.

Here is my code I did for now without the delete button :

HTML part :

```
<h1>Titre</h1>
<h3>Sous-titre</h3>
<input type="search" id="new-task" placeholder="Ajouter une tâche..." />
<button onclick="répondre()"> OK </button>

<hr />
<div id="todo-list">
  <h2>Todo list</h2>
  <ul id="liste"
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="date">
  <input type="datetime-local" value="2023-03-29T11:30" disabled="true" min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2023-06-14T00:00">
  <div />
```

JAVASCRIPT part :

```
var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("memtasks"));

for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
  var t = tasks[i];
  var ul = document.getElementById("liste");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function répondre() {
  console.log("test", tasks);
  var task = document.getElementById("new-task").value;
  if (!task) {
    return;
  }

  tasks.push(task);
  console.log(tasks);
  localStorage.setItem("memtasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));

  var ul = document.getElementById("liste");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("new-task").value = "";
}
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific question about how to achieve this? So you know, `<ul id="liste"` is missing its ending `>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it. I added comments in the code for explanation.

```
  //I added a fallback to an empty array in case "memtasks" doesn't exist in
  //localStorage
  var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("memtasks")) || [];

  //I refactored the code for creating a task in an "addTaskToDOM" function 
  //because it's used when you open the web page and when you add a new task.
  function addTaskToDOM(task) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("liste");
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    //When a task is added to the DOM, you can create a "delete" button that 
    //will use the "deleteTask" function when clicked
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.textContent = "delete";
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click",
      e => deleteTask(e.target.closest("li"))
    );
  
    li.appendChild(task);
    li.appendChild(deleteButton);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  //"deleteTask" will remove the task from the DOM 
  // update the tasks array 
  // then update the localStorage.
  function deleteTask(task) {
    task.remove();
    tasks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#liste li"))
              .map(li => li.childNodes[0].textContent);
    localStorage.setItem("memtasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }

  function répondre() {
    var task = document.getElementById("new-task").value;

    if (!task) {
      return;
    }

    tasks.push(task);
    addTaskToDOM(document.createTextNode(task));
    localStorage.setItem("memtasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    document.getElementById("new-task").value = "";
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    addTaskToDOM(document.createTextNode(tasks[i]));
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much, and now how do I customize it? I just posted a question about it if you could help it woud be great